# horizontal scroll-able table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am reproducing my problem in [responsive design for html wide table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578325/responsive-design-for-html-wide-table). basically I have a very wide table and the table will be placed inside a div with ten columns width (I am using bootstrap here). The problem is 
the body of the table is bounded by the body width the rest was truncated, when I scroll the table to right I can only see the header and the body was empty.

```js
$('table').on('scroll', function () {
    $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
 .ten.columns {
    width: 82.6666666667%;
  }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns {
    margin-left: 8.66666666667%;
  }
}

/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
table {
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
table thead, table tbody {
    display: block;
}
table tbody {
    max-height: 307px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
table th, table td {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
table th:first-child,
table td:first-child {
  min-width:200px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
table th:last-child,
table td:last-child {
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='row ten columns offset-by-one'>
  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
              <th>Column 3</th>
              <th>Column 4</th>
              <th>Column 5</th>
              <th>Column 6</th>
              <th>Column 7</th>
              <th>Column 8</th>
              <th>Column 9</th>
              <th>Column 10</th>
              <th>Column 11</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
              <td>Row 3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
              <td>Row 4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
              <td>Row 5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
              <td>Row 6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
              <td>Row 7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
              <td>Row 8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
              <td>Row 9</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
              <td>Row 10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
              <td>Row 11</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: to view my problem accurately, please go to https://codepen.io/zh1611/pen/pZdLNZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
table thead, table tbody {
    display: block;
}
```

to :

```
table thead, table tbody {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also you can change it to `display: inline` or `display: table` and it will work fine.

[Here](https://www.bayt.com/en/specialties/q/345753/what-is-the-diffrence-bettween-display-table-display-block-display-inline-block-disblay-inline/) there is a short answer about what is the difference between `display: table`, `display: inline`, `display: block` and `display: inline-block` :

Comment: add-on: quick question, do you know how to freeze the first column?

Comment: @user466130 you mean first column always show even after scroll table?

Comment: it is to make some row sticky, not quite close to what i need :)